# Encoding Issue with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, encoding, utf-8

In MySQL with phpmyadmin my text looks like:

& eacute; <-- no space, added to see.

When I read it into PHP and print it to the error_log it looks like:

\xe9

When I try to look at it in a web browser it looks like:

�

It should look like this in the web browser:

é

Does anyone know what is wrong?

my html page has the tags

```
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
and
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` or something similar to your page so the browser will display it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Is your database set to use **uft8_unicode_ci** charset?

Comment: I went into phpmyadmin > click "operations" > then changed the Collation to utf8_general_ci

Comment: On the home tab of phpmyadmin under database server it says: Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: You should change collation directly to you database, table AND columns of table.

Comment: Change phpmyadmin collation set only change exibition collation, not table/column collation.

Each table column may have different collation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I had to change the my.cnf file my MySQL

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```